# Is there any different version of Google chrome using in China PC?

Tags: google-chrome, cross-browser, browser

We did multilingual website for our client. English version working on chrome. But, when we run English language website on china PC using Google chrome browser. Font-size of the specific text looks big.

we specified font-size of the text as 9px. even in "Styles" it shows 9px. But on "Computed" it shows values as 12px. Its so weired to this see value. even if we reduce to 7 or 6px, no change in the font reduction. If it exceeds about 12px only we can see the layout difference.

Any one faced similar issue before? Please help me to solve if you have heard something similar in your development tactics.

Thanks